# JBOSS WS regex ampersand

Tags: xsd, jaxb, jbossws

I'm new to web-services and I encountered a problem. There is a web-service running on JBOSS 6, when on client side we send data with '&' we encounter such error 'The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference' ? Couldn't find the solution in web.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the server is receiving an XML document; in the strings you send, you (or some agent acting on your behalf) need to escape XML's delimiters (replace '&' with '&' and '<' with '<') before transmission of the message.  This has nothing much to do with XSD; it's basic XML syntax.